# How to get sum of votes for an item in a DB?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on functionality that lets users vote on particular items.  I made an item table and a votes table. The votes table has vote column that will either have 1 or -1

When getting items, I am assuming that I will just do a join on items and votes, and sum up the votes column.

Is that a scalable approach?  So far I have this query:

```
select item_id , title , description , votes from items 
    left join votes on
    items.item_id = votes.item_id
    order by item_id desc
```

But how do I use the sum function on the votes column in the same query?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select item_id , title , description , sum(votes) as totalVotes from items 
    left join votes on
    items.item_id = votes.item_id
    group by votes.item_id
    order by item_id desc
```

Comment: Beat me by -> <- that much... +1

Comment: @Marc I'll go and upvote your other answers so you feel better :)  Thanks guys!

Comment: btw would I still get that item like this: $vote = $row['votes'];

Comment: @GeekedOut, that would now be `$row['totalVotes'] due to `as totalVotes` alias in the query

Comment: You'll need `$vote = $row['totalVotes'];` to get the sum value.